# -bash: command not found

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

When I try to do anything from a command line, on every command I get the error:

```
-bash: command not found
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/821614/edit) your question with the error output when you run a command. Or specifically which command gives you the error.

Comment: "on every command"? really? type "echo" and see what it returns

Answer (score 2):

Your listing says you tried to run `-bash` literally, with the hyphen at beginning. Compare with this example:

```
$ asd
asd: command not found
$
```

Try issuing the command again without the leading hyphen.